# Can't load image in ImageViewAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't get an image to load into an ImageViewAsync. There's just a blank where the image should be. I've tried both synchronous and asychronous approaches.
I have the image placeholderProfileImage.png in the mipmap folders. I walked the debugger through the binding code and all appears to be in order. Note that I removed other code that populates the view with text. That part is working. What am I doing wrong with respect to the image?

profilePhotoImageView is defined in a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/acquaintanceRow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
        android:id="@+id/profilePhotoImageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/profilePhotoTransition" />
>
```

The view holder class contains ProfilePhotoImageView:

```
internal class MyViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
    // removed stuff for brevity

        public ImageViewAsync ProfilePhotoImageView { get; }

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            MyRow = itemView;

    // removed stuff for brevity

            ProfilePhotoImageView = MyRow.FindViewById<ImageViewAsync>(Resource.Id.profilePhotoImageView);
        }
    }
```

Binding code:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
var viewHolder = holder as MyViewHolder;

string photoUrl = "placeholderProfileImage.png:";

FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter taskParameter = ImageService.LoadFileFromApplicationBundle(photoUrl);
FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter taskParameter2 = taskParameter.Transform(new CircleTransformation());
taskParameter2.Into(viewHolder.ProfilePhotoImageView);

// tried asynchronous as well, nothing
//FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter taskParameter = ImageService.LoadUrl(photoUrl);
//FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter taskParameter2 = taskParameter.Transform(new CircleTransformation());
//taskParameter2.Into(viewHolder.ProfilePhotoImageView);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoadFileFromApplicationBundle` is loading the file from `Assets` not the mipmap folder. So you have to move the file to your `Assets` folder and set the build action to `AndroidAsset`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I copied the image to the `Assets` folder and then I checked the properties and by default the build action is `AndroidAsset`. I restarted Visual Studio and cleaned and built the solution for good measure, but still no image.I suspect what you say is necessary, but there must be more.

Comment: It's working now. I don't know what happened quite frankly. I didn't change the code. A re-build finally took hold or something.